# LALR Grammar Parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

suppose i have a grammar(`LALR` parsing)

```
 S->Ba|bBc
```

Can a parsing table be constructed(with `action` and `goto`)practically using some parser

Comment: Please ask this question on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shivi Your question has an answer that can have different opinions and hence doesn't belong here...

Comment: @bhushan firake what opinions please can you clarify

Comment: @Shivi LALR(1) or different? You are saying LALR parsing and in last line again you are again saying that "using some parser"

Comment: @Shivi: More info at this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwc3pUUahJk

Comment: @bhushan firake yes,I am talking of LALR(1).I know how to make parsing table manually.But if there are any parsers like Bison ,lex which would help to make the parsing table practically ,i am searching for that

Comment: @BhushanFirake There are only two possible opinions on this answer, 'yes' and 'no', and one of them is wrong. I don't agree that the question doesn't belong here. There are 'parsing' and 'compiler' tags that fit it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many parsers out there for what you are asking for.The one that has feature to parse them online is at this [link](http://www.supereasyfree.com/software/simulators/compilers/principles-techniques-and-tools/parsing-simulator/parsing-simulator.php). this parser has many options available. This is the practical  implementation where you need to pass the grammar and it wil generate the parsing tables for you. Not sure about the `action` and `goto`.

`Yacc` is also the one you can have look at. Here is the [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yacc).
Hope this helped you..